# posting to a rest service with restsharp

Tags: c#, rest

Ok, I'm assuming that this is an easy one, but I can't find my answer anywhere...  I have a client that needs to query a rest api through .net.  He sent me the url for the api, and a sample of the data.  This is what he sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<request>
<APIClientID>0</APIClientID >
<Version>0</Version>
<APIPassword>password</APIPassword >
<Function>functionName</Function >
<Params>
<UserId>(current-datetime)</UserId >
<page>example.aspx</page>
<application>appName</application>
<function>functionName</function>
</Params>
</request >
</root >
```

I'm using restsharp and I'm trying to do a post to the service.  But I keep just getting back the get page with the details for the api.  This is what I'm doing with restsharp...

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = url;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("APIClientID", "4");
request.AddHeader("Version", "0");
request.AddHeader("APIPassword", "password");
request.AddHeader("Function", "TransAPIStats");
request.AddHeader("Version", "0");
request.AddParameter("Client", "test client");
request.AddParameter("UserId", DateTime.Now.ToString());
request.AddParameter("Page", "example.aspx");
request.AddParameter("Application", "app");
request.AddParameter("Function", "function");

RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

any thoughts on where I'm going wrong would be greatly apprecaited!  I'm guessing that there is something about hte xml that I'm not translating properly to the restsharp call, but I'm lost at this point... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the POST body needs to be an XML document, use AddBody(). It defaults to serializing the object passed to it as XML. You could do this with an anonymous object that matches the schema you're trying to generate:

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = url;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddBody(new {
    root = new {
        request = new {
            APIClientID = 4,
            Version = 0,
            APIPassword = "password",
            Function = "TransAPIStats",
            Params = new {
                UserId = "abc",
                page = "example.aspx",
                Application = "hrblock-cb",
                Function = "ecb"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Or you could define a simple C# object that matches the schema and use that instead of the inline anonymous object.

If you need control over the serialization (the default should work based on the example data you show), you can implement your own ISerializer. Docs for that are the last section here: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization

Comment: Me thinks an XDocument Serializer would be a handy tool :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response John!  I added that in, however when I run it, I get the following error back: XmlException was unhandled: Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C.

Comment: probably best to move this to groups.google.com/group/restsharp where there will be more people that can help.