# Cannot PUT/POST using Rest Sharp using XML

Tags: c#, xml, http, rest, restsharp

I want to create/modify an issue on redmine using the PUT/POST methods of restSharp.
I cannot find valuable information about xml PUT/POST using Rest sharp. I tried various methods from restsharp.org like  `Addbody("test", "subject");` , `IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);` but there is no change in Redmine. What am I doing wrong?

POST gives a "Only get, **put**, and delete requests are allowed." message.

PUT gives a "Only get, **post**, and delete requests are allowed." message.

**My Code**

```
    RestClient client = new RestClient(_baseUrl);
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_user, _password);


    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("issues/{id}.xml", Method.POST);

    request.AddParameter("subject", "Testint POST");

    request.AddUrlSegment("id", "5");


    var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: At least explain why you downvote this post.

Comment: Conrad look at this StackOverFlow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747261/how-to-add-a-get-parameter-to-a-post-request-with-restsharp
if this doesn't help do a google search on C# Put/GET RestSharp example

Comment: I did, and the only examples given are in JSON not xml, I also tried to adapt their example to xml, and it still gives no change in redmine.

Comment: If you are wanting to do this with XML you may want to change your question to reflect this..

Comment: here is another link ..if you have XML also show the structure of the XML please.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917437/posting-to-a-rest-service-with-restsharp

Comment: @DJKRAZE , The link you sent is not related to my problem. Please tell me if something is unclear.

Comment: are you trying to do this using XML..? I am a bit confused based on one of your comments.. thanks

Comment: Can you post on how the REST method looks like to help you out.

Comment: Or perhaps both the request and response from Fiddler might help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the serialization. My `Issue` class contains object of various other classes which was causing a problem in the serialization.
This is how we did it:

```
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("issues/{id}.xml", Method.PUT);
    request.AddParameter("id", ticket.id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    request.XmlSerializer = new RedmineXmlSerializer();
    request.AddBody(ticket);

    RestClient client = new RestClient(_baseUrl);
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_user, _password);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok to me, I'm unsure if you need this but we added this header when using RestSharp for json against a WebAPI host:

```
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
```